# LibGDX: Vertical scrolling Texture

Tags: java, libgdx

Hi I am trying to make a texture vertically scrollable and am not able to get the correct behaviour.

Here is my code:

```
    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        if (startingy == 0 ) {
            startingy = (Gdx.input.getY())
                    / (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / MainGame.HEIGHT);
        }
        else if(getstart){
            startingy = startingy-scroll;
            getstart = false;

        }
        scroll = (Gdx.input.getY())
                / (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / MainGame.HEIGHT);

        if (startingy -scroll < 0) {
            startingy = 0;
            scroll = 0;
        }
        if (startingy > img.getHeight()) {
            startingy = img.getHeight();
        }
    } else {
        getstart = true;
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make it easier for yourself and use an `InputListener` and the `touchDragged` method. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling

When you have made an `InputListener` class you can simply set it as a listener by:

`Gdx.input.setInputProcesser(myProcesser);`